# How do I perform FFI calls inside ST monad

Tags: c, haskell, ffi

Good day!

The core of my project is written inside `ST` monad and I am trying to add some features that were implemented in C. I've implemented the FFI for all functions that I need:

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "codec/encode.h encode_symbol"
    encodeSymbol :: Ptr EncodingEnv
                 -> CShort            -- symbol to encode
                 -> Ptr Context
                 -> IO ()
```

Both `Context` and `EncodingEnv` are modified inside the C routine. I have working `Storable` instances for both `EncodingEnv` and `Context`. The simple `main` test program works well.

Nonetheless, all of the code that need to call these C routines lays inside the `ST` monad. I need to store these `Ptr`s to `EncodingEnv` and to `Context` somewhere.

How should I deal with long-lived mutable `C` structures inside the `ST` monad and how do I call these `C` routines? My suggestion is to use `STRef (Foreign?Ptr Context)`, but how do I `malloc` these pointers from `ST`? I fail to find it in any examples or tutorials.

Thank you

Comment: You use `unsafeIOtoST` : http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-ST-Unsafe.html (note: unsafe means VERY unsafe. this should be a last resort)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ST` monad is really intended for working with Haskell-allocated state like `STRef` and `STArray`.

If the things you want to call out to don't have externally visible side-effects and just manipulate the structures you'll be passing them, it's probably "morally" ok to use [`unsafeIOToST`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.6.1/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad-ST.html#v%3aunsafeIOToST) to call them.

You'll need to take care that you don't let your pointers escape the specific `ST` computation they are used in as you won't get the normal safety benefits guaranteed by the phantom `s` parameter to `ST`.

Using `STRef (ForeignPtr ...)` won't really help in itself, but perhaps you might use a `newtype` wrapper that uses the phantom type parameter `s` to give a little extra self-imposed safety.

Comment: C routines do not perform any "side" effects indeed rather than modification of provided data; so, I'll try to use `unsafeIOToST` function. Will `ptr <- usafeIOToST mallocForeignPtr` work well or will the finalizer screw up? Thank you for your answer, I'll accept it as soon as I'll get a working prototype of that.

Comment: You should call `unsafeIOtoST . finalizeForeignPtr` as well. Even better: isolate your memory/ffi operations, do them in `IO` and then call `unsafeIOtoST` on that entire function, instead of calling it multiple times. Also, `unsafeIOtoST` is safe even if your functions have visible side effects, as long as those side effects are fully contained in the resulting `ST` thread.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to isolate the whole part into a single `IO` action, but it is highly probable that I'll need to interleave `C` calls with existent `ST` actions. In that case, if I need to call `finalizeForeignPtr` anyway, why don't I use bare `malloc` and `free`?

Comment: If you use `newForeignPtr` you can't guarantee the finalizer will be run if you use `unsafeIOtoST`. You may not need to run the finalizer. If you only use `mallocForeignPtr` there should be no finalizers to run. Besides, `ForeignPtr` is optimized compared to just `Ptr`

Comment: @user2407038: why do you say that `unsafeIOtoST` would interfere with a `ForeignPtr` finalizer?  I do not see any way that would cause a problem.